# How can i handle many children viewmodels in MVVM?

Tags: dependency-injection, mvvm

Let's suppose i have a viemwodel which requires a lot of different children viewmodels.

An example could be a settings menu: the main viewmodel should be able to load large number of children viewmodels (in the example image there are 3, but they could be an arbitrary number, even up to ~20)

All of the viewmodels are substantially different from each other.

[image: diagram of a viewmodel with three children models]

The usual way i organize child viewmodels is the following:

```
MainViewModel(ChildViewModelFactory fac)
{
    this.factory = fac;
}

...
// later, when the child must be loaded

var newViewModel = fac.invoke();
```

While this works correctly when the MainViewModel has a small number of children (like 1-3) it can become verbose and "smelly" when the MainViewModel needs a lot of children (a constructor with ~20 parameter doesn't sound good).

How can i approach this?

Answer (score 1):

### Abstraction

Consider abstracting the layout problem. Eg:

- a MenuView is a list of children, arranged vertically following some rules.
- A GridView is a 2D array of children, each instantiated into its cell following some rules.

This reduces the problem of 20 unique children, with unique location information, and unique variable names to a standardised organisation.

### Lifecycle

Don't have the view responsible for dealing with so much life-cycle on its child components. Have a ProtoView which holds the factories for each child, and when its called to instantiate it returns a real view with real children.